# Merge local Windows 10 account to my Microsoft account

Tags: windows, windows-10

I just installed my Windows 10 PC this Tuesday and installed all bunch of software that I need for my work and hobbies.
That's a lot of apps and time spent on installing and setting them up.

Then today, I just found that I logged in a local Windows 10 account, but once I switched to my Microsoft account which is associated with my Hotmail address, all installed apps(I installed them for All Users) need to be installed again, that's such a waste of space of my Hard Drive disk.

May I just merge the local Windows 10 account into my Microsoft account?

So that the app installed will be immediately available?

Comment: Have you tried to simply link the account while logged into the local account?  If you already have a local account, linked to a Microsoft account, you can't have two local profiles linked to the same Microsoft Account.  You will have to choose one account to be associated with the account.  Windows has no mechanism to merge user profiles, you have two local profiles, one is currently linked to your Microsoft Account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You logged in a new account. Instead, you should just log your Microsoft account in on your local account.

So,log in to your old account, the local only one, then open the User settings and log your Microsoft account in there on the current user.

Comment: in my case, I need to remove the Microsoft account I added and then logging into my local account and do what you said here :) thanks